# IE7 automatically open xml file error

Tags: security, internet-explorer, download, web-content

Currently each link type http:monsite/monfichier.xml, the file will automatically open in IE without asking me to download it, the problem is that my file contains DTD so that it can not find a poster error "error opening file".

The problem persists even after changing the MIME server weblogic application / octet-stream

Is there a parameter change in IE? (for have download box directly)

Thank you in advance

i have change many option in securty (download no automatic etc..) but nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to send the following header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.xml
```